# Why does my app make the recording (pulsing red) status bar appear when it isn't recording?

Tags: ios, core-audio, avaudiosession

My app sometimes uses the microphone, but even when I am not using the microphone, the red status bar appears momentarily when leaving my app.

I have set AVAudioSession's category to SoloAmbient. When I record, I set it to PlayAndRecord, and when I am done I set it back to SoloAmbient. But even when the category is SoloAmbient I still see the red status bar.

Even when my app has not accessed the microphone at all I am still getting this red status bar behavior. I do **not** have the app configured for background audio. Any ideas what might be making the system think that I am recording?

**EDIT:** After some experimentation, it looks like I can prevent the app from causing the red status bar on launch by delaying creating of the recording AUGraph until I actually start recording.

However, I still see the red status bar after stopping recording. When I stop recording, I stop the AUGraph and dispose of it and change the AVAudioSession category back to SoloAmbient. But I still see the red status bar when I switch away from the app.

Answer (score -2):

After a long long long long long research and hurdles I found out simple solution for this follow as below

In Targets->General->Deployment Info check the HideStatusBar Option

like below!

[image]

And in the ViewController (Which one you kept as RootViewController) in viewDidAppear add this line of code...

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
```

Because when you uncheck HideStatusBar Option and your app needs any background process or audio related process then the status bar will become red with enlarged height. If you dont want status bar in entire app then dont add the above line in viewDidAppear and check HideStatusBar Option.

Comment: Doesn't sounds like a real solution. I face the same problem, too. I think there's still a progress running in the background.